# Android Radio button text is bold

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a radio button using xml. However, for some reason the text is bold. 
Is there any way  I can make it non bold? I tried the android:textStyle but it does not seem to have an effect on radio button text

Any idea how?
Thanks

Comment: Radio button has a darker shade of black as default text color. I thought it was bold as well, but later found that it was just a color change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
your_radioButton.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
```